# Can posting "howsecureismypassword" results be a security risk?

Tags: password-cracking

Say that someone asked how secure my password is, if I give them the https://howsecureismypassword.net/ results of it, (especially if I disable the named numbers mode,) can that person brute force with the website's algorithm and possibly find my password?

Comment: Eventually, maybe. But you do rotate your password, right? Why not change a character or two?

Comment: do you mean the details? Like length, character combinations, etc.?

Comment: @StefHeylen I didn't consider that while asking, but containing both cases in an answer would be better. If you want only one: No, just the amount of years given by the website, for example 82346328236000 years.

Comment: This website is utter idiocy. No, `P@ssword` is not significantly harder to guess than `password`.

Comment: Might be a good idea to run such a site and log all passwords and wait for users bragging how good there password is. Then just compare their claim against the logged passwords.

Comment: @SteveDL good thing it never claims to be accurate.

Comment: Note to self: If I want everyone's auth tokens, I only need to hack "howsecureismypassword.net".

Comment: @ParthianShot [obligatory xkcd](http://xkcd.com/792/)

Comment: Wouldn't the only right answer be: "No"? ... Testing a password without the owner of https://howsecureismypassword.net/ knowing where you use it or with what username it has no risk whatsoever for you.

Answer (score 2):

By posting those results, you are limiting the pool of guesses the person has to use. However, this does not make brute forcing faster in a practical way, it simply limits the guesses the person will try. With a strong password, this brings diminishing returns -- excluding guesses without numbers or symbols doesn't help all too much.

However there is one exception: if the site reports you're using a "commonly used password" then it makes brute forcing extremely fast. And if you're using a password from that list, you deserve it!

Comment: -1. If you are using a commonly used password, you're already screwed. Posting the results in that case makes no difference.

Answer (score -4):

There should be no risk. The password you enter on https://howsecureismypassword.net/ is in no way related to where you actually use it. (Or don't tell the one who knows where you use it that you used https://howsecureismypassword.net/ for this :)

Say you test your password that you use on amazon.com ... You can enter that fine on https://howsecureismypassword.net/. Als long as there is no relation to that fact that you're using it on amazon.

Comment: Ever heard of [credential stuffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credential_stuffing)? Trying a couple passwords on many websites is a lot easier than trying millions of passwords on one website.